# Is there a workaround for WMI Windows Agent connection failure after Microsoft KB5004442 security update?

Tags: windows, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, dcom

- When a windows build node is configured with 'Let Jenkins control this Windows agent as a Windows Service', the connection fails with following log:

  ```
  [2022-01-18 07:24:29] [windows-agents] Connecting to **********
  ERROR: Message not found for errorCode: 0x80010111
  org.jinterop.dcom.common.JIException: Message not found for errorCode: 0x80010111
      at org.jinterop.dcom.core.JIComServer.init(JIComServer.java:580)
      at org.jinterop.dcom.core.JIComServer.initialise(JIComServer.java:481)
      at org.jinterop.dcom.core.JIComServer.<init>(JIComServer.java:445)
      at org.jvnet.hudson.wmi.WMI.connect(WMI.java:59)
      at hudson.os.windows.ManagedWindowsServiceLauncher.launch(ManagedWindowsServiceLauncher.java:208)
      at hudson.slaves.SlaveComputer.lambda$_connect$0(SlaveComputer.java:293)
      at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$2.call(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:46)
      at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$2.call(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:80)
      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
  Caused by: org.jinterop.dcom.common.JIRuntimeException: Message not found for errorCode: 0x80010111
      at org.jinterop.dcom.core.JIRemActivation.read(JIRemActivation.java:192)
      at ndr.NdrObject.decode(NdrObject.java:36)
      at rpc.ConnectionOrientedEndpoint.call(ConnectionOrientedEndpoint.java:137)
      at rpc.Stub.call(Stub.java:113)
      at org.jinterop.dcom.core.JIComServer.init(JIComServer.java:568)
      ... 11 more
  ```
- The build node displays the following log message in the event viewer:

  - source: DistributedCOM
  - Event ID: 10036
  - Level: Error

  ```
  The server-side authentication level policy does not allow the user ***** from address ***** to activate DCOM server. 
  Please raise the activation authentication level at least to RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_PKT_INTEGRITY in client application.
  ```
- Environment:

  - jenkins controller: 2.319.2 on centos7, adoptium jdk-11.0.13+8, Windows Agents v1.8 plugin
  - jenkins build node: Windows 10 Enterprise, 10.0.19042 Build 19042, **includes updates through 2022-01-13**, adoptium jdk-11.0.13+8
- The *Troubleshooting WMI Windows Agents* page at https://github.com/jenkinsci/windows-slaves-plugin/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.adoc was reviewed for possible causes without success.
- The event log message on the build node is described in the following security update: KB5004442—Manage changes for Windows DCOM Server Security Feature Bypass (CVE-2021-26414) https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb5004442-manage-changes-for-windows-dcom-server-security-feature-bypass-cve-2021-26414-f1400b52-c141-43d2-941e-37ed901c769c
- Editing the registry setting as described in KB5004442 followed by a reboot of the build node had no effect. The system log message is still generated.
- Please note that the behavior changes section in KB5004442 show that the bypass will *no longer be an option* after Q2 2022:

  - June 8, 2021 Hardening changes disabled by default but with the ability to enable them using a registry key.
  - Q1 2022 Hardening changes enabled by default but with the ability to disable them using a registry key.
  - Q2 2022 Hardening changes enabled by default with no ability to disable them. By this point, you must resolve any compatibility issues with the hardening changes and applications in your environment.

Any workarounds, solutions, or debugging tips are appreciated!

Comment: The Jenkins ticket https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-67604 filed in January 2022 remains in an Open/Critical state with no activity from the authors as of August 2022. 

Our organization has retired all usage of 'Let Jenkins control this Windows agent as a Windows Service' (aka WMI Windows agent) and now using  'Launch agents via SSH'.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as far as I found out, you could work with the Registry to set a Key, but that would open a Security Breach, so, in fact, no viable solution :
-> https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb5004442-manage-changes-for-windows-dcom-server-security-feature-bypass-cve-2021-26414-f1400b52-c141-43d2-941e-37ed901c769c

Comment: As noted in original post, the registry key workaround did not work as expected. Perhaps Microsoft has resolved the key issue, but I have not tried it. I no longer use this plugin.